# Amending code to make it list some files in a directory, rather than all

Tags: c#, strings

The method `list_all()` is the code I am starting with. It just lists all files in "c:\windows".

I want to adjust it to list only the first 10 files (if there are as many files as that there).

I can see that `Directory.GetFiles(sDir)` returns an array of string.  The original method `list_all()`, takes all of them.  I want mine to just take the first 10, or if there's less than 10 then all of them.  But i've added four lines of code and used a list, to do it. My amended method is `list_some()`

It's far from a disaster, but I'm sure there's a better way though I'm not sure.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            static void list_all()
            {
                string sDir = "c:\\windows";

                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(f);
                }

            }

            static void list_some()
            {
                string sDir="c:\\windows";

                List<string> lstsomefiles = new List<string>();
                int count = Directory.GetFiles(sDir).Length;
                string[] strs_fileslst = Directory.GetFiles(sDir);

                for (int i = 0; i < count && i < 10; i++) lstsomefiles.Add(strs_fileslst[i]);

                foreach (string f in lstsomefiles)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(f);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ better?

Comment: Maybe I should have linked to [this help center page: _How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)... it is an improvement but hopefully, after reading that page, you understand what would make it even better...

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, where we review actual working code from your project. The function names `blah_all` and `blah_some` as well as the variable name `lstsomefiles` seem more hypothetical than real code. In C# this code would also be in a class, and that I don't see. As Sam indicated above, please read the Asking section of the Code Review Guidelines.

Comment: @pacmaninbw i've now included the class and improved the function names. I made a simple example to give a simple easily demonstrable code that gets to the crux of the question I am asking. Maybe my question is more for stackoverflow if you don't want simple easily demonstrable code?

Comment: We require **concrete code** from a project with sufficient context to understand how that code is used. **Pseudocode**, stub code, **hypothetical code** & obfuscated code are outside the scope of this site. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yes I saw from asking somebody in chat, you aren't really looking to run the code. So my Q was better for SO. And people on this site would improve  by eye, code that they can't run, (And wouldn't really look to run it),  so that explains why you don't want  a  small demonstrable example of a problem. And so I also suppose it's more for so people don't commit code that defies conventions? And in those situations the poster is often unaware of what their issue(s) are, is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize the [`.Take()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1) method in LINQ which:

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence

Using this, your code would look as follows:

```
string sDir = "c:\\windows";

foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir).Take(10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Comment: wow that's beautiful

Comment: I think, you can optimize a bit by using `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Take(10)`. `EnumerateFiles` does not materialize all the file names in an array before returning. It operates directly on an Enumerator.

Comment: @barlop: In general, whenever you iterate over a list, 9 times out of 10 there's a cleaner LINQ approach. It's really worth having a look at what LINQ offers since it will dramatically improve code readability and prevent you from having to juggle list manipulation yourself.

Comment: As a second choice, supposing one didn't use LINQ, was what I wrote in my amendment unnecessarily laborious? what is a good way?

Comment: [To support @HenrikHansen's point](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles): "The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows: When you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, `EnumerateFiles` can be more efficient."